# Data is not written into CSV when I download CSV from Flask

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV that contains data of user activity over various social media apps ranging for a month
Here's  a snippet
[image]

for you reference:
Here is the content of the csv

```
date_time;timestamp;Instagram;Facebook;Snapchat;Twitter;TikTok;YouTube
2020-08-23__04:16:00.705612;1598148961;N;N;N;N;Y;N
2020-08-23__04:17:02.308588;1598149022;N;N;N;N;Y;N
2020-08-23__04:18:03.944537;1598149084;N;N;N;Y;Y;N
```

This contains more than 50,000 records.
Now when I upload this csv via my Flask App, and make changes in it and also download it, it does get downloaded and this is what I get.

[image]

All I do in my code is upload the CSV, and change the format of ``date_time``` from (Y-M-D__H-M-S.ms) to (Y-M-D H-M-S.ms), and when I download the new file, the data is not written into the csv properly

Here is my code for the same

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request, make_response
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import io

@app.route('/mainPage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_csv():
    if request.method=='POST':
        f=request.form['csvfile']
        dataset=pd.read_csv(f)
        df=pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=list(dataset.columns))
        date_time=[]
        dt=df['date_time']
        for i in range(len(dt)):
            cons=dt[i] #considering the current datetime object
            cons=cons.replace('__', ' ') 
            date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(cons, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            date_time.append(date_time_obj)

        df.drop(columns='date_time')
        col = df.columns.tolist()
        df['date_time']=date_time
        df = df[(['date_time']+col[1:])]
        si = io.StringIO()
        cw = csv.writer(si)
        cw.writerows(df)
        output = make_response(si.getvalue())
        output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=new.csv"
        output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
        return output
    return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some problems here.

```
df.drop(columns='date_time')
```

should be

```
df = df.drop(columns='date_time')
```

or

```
df.drop(columns='date_time', inplace=True)
```

Next, the insertion of the new data sounds overly complicated to me. You can just do

```
df.insert(loc=0, column="date_time", value=date_time)
```

Lastly, all that complex CSV output is possibly much easier with

```
df.to_csv(index=False)
```

Here's my full code (Python only, no Flask):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from io import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""
date_time;timestamp;Instagram;Facebook;Snapchat;Twitter;TikTok;YouTube
2020-08-23__04:16:00.705612;1598148961;N;N;N;N;Y;N
2020-08-23__04:17:02.308588;1598149022;N;N;N;N;Y;N
2020-08-23__04:18:03.944537;1598149084;N;N;N;Y;Y;N""")

def upload_csv():
    dataset=pd.read_csv(csvdata, delimiter=";")
    df=pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=list(dataset.columns))
    date_time=[]
    dt=df['date_time']
    for i in range(len(dt)):
        cons=dt[i] #considering the current datetime object
        cons=cons.replace('__', ' ')
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(cons, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        date_time.append(date_time_obj)

    df.drop(columns='date_time', inplace=True)
    df.insert(loc=0, column="date_time", value=date_time)
    return df.to_csv(index=False)


output = upload_csv()
```

Comment: @GlenVeigas: thanks for providing the data etc. Next time, try to make a [mre]. As you saw, it was possible to remove the need of Flask and reproduce it in a small Python program with all data included.

Comment: Yes, sir..Noted! I will do that.